# Does Linq to Sql have onChanging?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I am looking at   [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-37-cs.aspx) yet it uses the entity framework.

so I am wondering can I do the same thing with linq to sql and if so how? They seem to use this OnChaning thing but I don't know if linq to sql has it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The extensibility methods for the Changed/Changing events on each property are generated by the Linq to SQL designer.  You just need to have a partial class implementation of the entity that implements the extensibilty methods.

```
public partial class Entity
{
    public partial void OnIDChanging( int value )
    {
       ... some validation code...
    }
}
```

Comment: So I can do what the tutorial has with linq to sql?

Comment: Yes.  I didn't look at the tutorial in depth, but as far as the extensibility methods are concerned you should be ok.

Comment: Just did a quick test and tvanfosson is correct.  The On___Changing event will fire when the system detects a change to the property on a submit.